# Google Drive Api errors when compiling in Xcode 7 swift 2

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to experience the quickstartApp sample from Google and get the following compiler errors (Xcode 7 and swift 2) :

Value of type GTLQueryDrive has no member 'maxResults' and
Value of type GTLDriveFileList has no member 'items'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace query.maxResults with query.pageSize

```
for(GTLDriveFile *file in files.files)
    {
        NSLog(@"ext = %@", file.mimeType);
        //if(![file.mimeType isEqualToString:@"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"])
        //if(file.fileExtension)
            //NSLog(@"title : %@, and link = %@", file.name, file.contentHints.thumbnail.image);
    }
```

This is objective c